# The cleanest way to avoid multiple if-statements - object creation dependent on many params

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, design-patterns

I'm looking for the cleanest way to determine value without using multiple if-statements (or switch-case).

For example, I have following mapping table:
[image]

As you see, I need to consider 5 variables before I will be able to determine the exact value.

Using if-statements leads to embedded ifs nightmare.

I have two solutions in mind:

Very dirty - map of maps of maps of maps, etc. :

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,...>>> myMappings;
```

Involving a lot of code: Factory with sub-factories leading to final value - practically this is better for readability, but still this is if-statements encapsulated in classes.

What are your ideas?

Comment: What value are you trying to get here, based on which columns of the data above? Are you reading the data from a CSV file?

Comment: You could use a properties file, using as key the combination of your five columns concatenated (or separated by `.`) that would map your final value on your sixth column: `companyno.sweepType.vatRate.rrd.ctx=value`.

Comment: What about having the data stored in a table and retrieve it with select queries.

Comment: Not sure what value you want, and what columns you are using. "As you see" - No, sorry I don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd rather keep all those value in a table and only consider the final value I could obtain with a simple SQL query. You can chose other options but you should always keep those mapping in an external source (table, properties file...) you could modify if the requirements change.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by introducing a composite key. Just add all your fields into it and override `hashCode` and `equals` properly. After that you can put and get necessary values from some kind of `Map<CompositeKey, TaxCode>`.
As an illistration, not all fields are included and it's better to come up with a more meaningful name:

```
public class CompositeKey {

private final int companyNumber;
private final String sweepType;
private final int vatRate;

public CompositeKey(int companyNumber, String sweepType, int vatRate) {
    this.companyNumber = companyNumber;
    this.sweepType = sweepType;
    this.vatRate = vatRate;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    CompositeKey that = (CompositeKey) o;

    if (companyNumber != that.companyNumber) return false;
    if (vatRate != that.vatRate) return false;
    return Objects.equals(this.sweepType, that.sweepType);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = companyNumber;
    result = 31 * result + (sweepType != null ? sweepType.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + vatRate;
    return result;
}
}
```

So then you can:

```
Map<CompositeKey, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new CompositeKey(200, "SLT", 0), "Value 1");
String value = map.get(new CompositeKey(200, "SLT", 0));
```

Comment: Eclipse/InteliJ/IDEA will happily auto-generate the `equals` and `hashcode` methods for whichever fields you want, so it should look a lot less painful than nested `if` blocks.